# Differentiable norm preserving map is a linear isometry?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Suppose $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable and $||\Phi(x)|| = ||x||$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Does it already follow that $\Phi$ is a linear isometry?

If $\Phi$ is only continuous we could simply take $\Phi(x) = |x|$ in case $n = 1$ for a counterexample.

Do you know any counterexamples or a proof? Is surjectivity maybe the point? Does it hold if we require a priori surjectivity?

Comment: Linear isomety is by definition a linear map between normed spaces $f:V\to W$ such that $||f(x)|| = ||x||~\forall~x\in V$. Of curse linear isometries are injective becuase its kernel is $0$, but they need not be surjective. In the case it is surjective we say that $f$ is a global linear isometry.

Comment: You are right for $n=1$. I think you should ba able to find a differentiable self-map of the unit circle in $\Bbb{R}^2$ that is not a rotation or a reflection, which will extend to a counterexample for $n > 1$.

Comment: @Marcos yes, you are right. But in my special case the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ are both $n$, so surjectivity would be automatically given by injectivity.

Comment: On the other hand, if you assume that $\Phi(0) = 0$ and $\Phi$ preserves the distance between any two points, i.e., for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $$|\Phi(y)-\Phi(x)| = |y-x|,$$ then $\Phi$ is a lnear isometry. You do not even have to assume that $\Phi$ is differentiable or even continuous (that's an obvious consequence of the assumptions).

Comment: @Deane yeah thanks. This result I knew before. In retrospect it was a silly question in view of Rob Arthan's comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not true. Consider for example $n=2$ and
$x\mapsto\left(\begin{matrix} \cos(r^2) & -\sin(r^2)  \\\sin(r^2) & \;\;\cos(r^2) \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} x_1  \\ x_2 \end{matrix}\right)$, where $r=|x|$.

On each circle of radius $r$ this is a rotation with rotation angle $r^2$, so lengths of vectors don't change. However it is not a linear map, since the rotation angles change with the norm.